# When I use golang's append function to create a 2D slice, the previous value in the slice changes

Tags: go

Here is my code:

```golang
package src

func Subsets(nums []int) [][]int {
    var sets = make([][]int, 0)
    var t = make([]int, 0)
    sets = append(sets, t)
    for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
        for _, v := range sets {
            t = append(v, nums[i])
            sets = append(sets, t)      }
    }
    return sets
}
```

Test data is []int{1,2,3,4,5}
I debug it. found that:

When calculate sets[22], the sets[15] from []int{1,2,3,4} change to []int{1,2,3,5}

What happened.

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/slices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the elements of `sets` kind of reference the same slice.

You better create a new slice for each element of `sets`. Appending does not create a new slice.

Here is a fix which copies the previous vector of `sets` instead of simply extending it.

```
package src

func Subsets(nums []int) [][]int {
    var sets = make([][]int, 0)
    var t = make([]int, 0)
    sets = append(sets, t)
    for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
        for _, v := range sets {
            t = append([]int(nil), v...) // t is copy of v
            t = append(t, nums[i])
            sets = append(sets, t)
        }
    }
    return sets
}
```

Tested here: https://play.golang.org/p/OZ9nN_t3w9D